# A property of the canonical inclusion $i: L^2(0,1)\to L^1(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Prove that the image of  the canonical inclusion $i: L^2(0,1)\to L^1(0,1)$  is a countable union of closed sets with empty internal part. Can anyone give me any idea on the solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the image of the unit ball of $L^2$ in $L^1$.

If you need more hints, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: Thank you. the image of the unit ball is inclused in the unit ball of $L^1$ but I can't see how to proceed. Can you help me more?

Comment: @user62138 $L^2$ is reflexive, hence its closed unit ball is ...?

Comment: weakly compact (even sequential weakly compact)

Comment: @user62138 Weakly compact is what we want. And convex. Now, since the inclusion is continuous for the norm topologies, it is also continuous for ...?

Comment: @DanielFischer: but it doesn't imply that is continous for the weak topology...

Comment: @user62138 it implies that it is continuous for the weak **topologies**, on both spaces.

Comment: @DanielFischer: OK. Then I consider $A_n=(f\in L^2: ||f||_{L^1}\leq n)$. They are compacts for the weak topology. Has empty internal part because they are bounded. They are weakly closed because compacts in a Hausdorf space. Is this right?

Comment: @user62138 Right. And that makes them norm-closed too.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you.

Comment: I originally aimed at $B_n = \{ f \in L^1 : \|f\|_{L^2} \le n\}$... Your $A_n$ is not closed, is it?